# What should I use to create this kind of product image functionality?

Tags: product

Here is aliexpress single product page. I want this kind of product page. The question is how I can create this kind of image fature.

Like, when I hover a small image it load big image in same div.
It only load when I hover or click otherwise it don't so it decrease page load time.

Do you have any advise or any JavaScript plugin, or anything that can help me?

[Link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Justin-Bieber-Poster-Hip-Hop-Harajuku-Streetwear-Hoodie-Hooded-Man-Letters-Justin-Bieber-Purpose-Tour-Security/32749040850.html?spm=2114.01010108.3.19.DqjInY&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10065_10068_10000074_10502_10000032_10504_119_10000025_10000029_430_10000028_10060_10000067_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10059_9871_10099_10000022_9875_10000013_10103_10102_10000016_10096_10000018_10000019_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10107_10050_10106_10051_10000053_10000007_10000050_10084_10083_10000047_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10115_10000041_10000044_10078_10079_10000038_429_10073_10000035_10121-9871_9875_10502_10504,searchweb201603_1,afswitch_3,single_sort_2_default&btsid=23a5ef88-7eca-4972-8153-6f8f5a192f7b)

Answer (score 0):

There are many jQuery plugins out to do this task Like

- http://redopop.com/loupe/
- http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3
- http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Magnifier/
- http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.
but I don't talk about magnifire script.

you can see when someone click side small image, only then other image loaded in same div.

how I can create this kind of functionality?
I think this decrease my page load time.

thanks